# Add Control programmatically, UI is not updating

Tags: maui

I am just playing arround with .Net MAUI.
I want to retrieve information from a Rest service and based on the result I want to add Buttons programmatically to a VerticalStackLayout.
When I debug the solution the buttons are added to the VerticalStackLayout but the UI is not updated.

Here the code Snippet

```cs
var  btn  = new Button();
btn.Text = "Button " + count + " added";
btn.Clicked += OnCounterClicked;
btn.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
VLayout.Add(btn);
```

Here the XAML

```xml
<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="VLayout"
        Spacing="25" 
        Padding="30,0" 
        VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Image
            Source="dotnet_bot.png"
            SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
            HeightRequest="200"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />            
        <Label 
            Text="Hello, World!"
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
            FontSize="32"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />        
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
            SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
            FontSize="18"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Entry
            x:Name="entry"
            Placeholder="Enter text"
            TextChanged="OnTextChanged"
            Completed="OnTextCompleted" />           
        <Button 
            x:Name="KommenBtn"
            Text="Kommen"
            SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
            Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Button 
            x:Name="GehenBtn"
            Text="Gehen"
            SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
            Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 5):

To update UI after a change that affects the hierarchy (or positions) of controls:

```cs
    (VLayout as IView).InvalidateArrange();
```

NOTE: This is roughly equivalent to Xamarin.Forms `layout.ForceLayout();`

If not already in code running on UI MainThread, wrap it in Dispatch:

```cs
Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
    (VLayout as IView).InvalidateArrange());
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer!! Unfortunately the bevahior still stays the same, UI isn't updated. Do you have an additional hint?

thanks in advance & BW

Comment: Hi.. having same issue - Any solution? thx

Answer (score 4):

Try to update UI on main thread , you can wrap your code into  `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch` .

##### Sample code

```java
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
{
    var  btn  = new Button();
    btn.Text = "Button " + count + " added";
    btn.Clicked += OnCounterClicked;
    btn.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
    VLayout.Add(btn);
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
{

    (verticalstacklayout as IView).InvalidateArrange();
    DetailItemTextBox deta = new DetailItemTextBox();
    deta.Text = "World";
deta.TextFontHeight = 30;
    verticalstacklayout.Children.Add(deta as IView);});
```

Tried to update UI on main thread, but not adding to layout.